# Android App Presentation

Tags: android, video-capture, jing

I wanted to make a video presentation of my android application. i know i can make the presentation by holding a camcorder in front of the screen and give walkthrough the application. But is there any other way this can be done, something on the lines of JingProject for windows wherein you can record your activities on your screen in a video.

is there a tool that can help me achieve the same on my android device

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this http://code.google.com/p/androidscreencast/

Update : I would like to add [Droid@Screen](http://blog.ribomation.com/2010/01/21/droidscreen/) | [Credit/Source Question No 2844343](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844343/how-to-show-a-live-presentation-from-an-android-phone)