# How to create Vidio presentation for the android app

Tags: android

I have developed one android app and now I wants create one video presentation for that app
for the demo purpose. Can anybody please tell me, how can I do this.? Is there any tool to do this..? One guy have asked this question before, but I didn't get the answer suggested there [Please see that question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627072/android-app-presentation)

Comment: Tagged as Android, but the user is asking for how to make a video presentation. Irrelevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://mymobiler.com/

Great tool for sharing screen and capturing video.